# Visualizing tracks from OpenCV Blob tracker

Tags: opencv

Is there an easy way to visualize the data form the OpenCV blob tracker? I have the output as a YAML file. I generally use Excel to visualize my data, but reading in this data into Excel is too messy. I could write a program to take this file and rewrite it into something easily imported into Excel but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if there is an easier way.

Comment: In case anyone else is facing this problem, one solution is to use the bt_gen parameter with the value RawTracks that is part of the example blobtracker.cpp. This spits out a file of <x,y,sx,sy>... where each line is the coordinates for one object. You can easily re-write this to output it into any format you want.